# Bash reading from /dev/tcp, without external binaries

Tags: bash, tcp

I'm trying to read files with bash tcp socket,

So on one host I do,

```
nc -l 8888 < /etc/passwd
```

And on another machine,

```
echo </dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8888
```

But it didn't read the file as expected, I got an empty line.

I know `cat < /dev/tcp/xxx/xxxx` works, but can I do that without external binaries?

### EDIT

So I tried `$()` syntax,

```
# echo $(</dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8888) > file
bash: /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8888: No such file or directory
```

Comment: `echo "$(</dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8888)"` ?

Comment: `echo` doesn't do what you think it does. You probably meant to use `cat`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `while` loop:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
done < /dev/tcp/localhost/8888
```